# filefrag on BTRFS

Tags: linux, filesystems, btrfs

I did this command on a BTRFS partition:

filefrag -e "/some path/some file"

Then I opened a hexeditor and opened the disk and went to the supposed physical addresses of the filefragments. The blocks were not there. Additionally: I tried a brute search on 1 block and discovered, that this block is several bytes off.

How should one correctly use filefrag on BTRFS? Is filefrag broken on BTRFS?

PS: I know, filefrag returns incorrect addresses of inline extents.

Comment: Is your file or file system using compression?

Comment: The compression setting is irrelevant. The questions are whether filefrag even correctly functions on BTRFS at all and how one can retrieve the physical addresses of the filefragments (extents) on BTRFS.

Comment: I suppose the Glossary and Gotchas sections of [`btrfs.wiki.kernel.org`](https://btrfs.wiki.kernel.org) could be out-of-date.  And if they were out-of-date, perhaps the comments there on `filefrag` might also be out-of-date. Or maybe ...

Comment: I appreciate your reference to the wiki page. Yes, the information thereon is moreover inaccurate not only outdated. 'filefrag' returns wildly inaccurate physical addresses of extents. 'filefrag' is unable to return the physical addresses of inline extents (whether compressed or raw).

Comment: Maybe `btrfs inspect-internal ...` or even [`shujianyang/btrForensics`](https://github.com/shujianyang/btrForensics) might provide the information you are looking for.